# jQuery - Bind Plugin to Textbox with Dynamic Class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have the following function to turn a normal text field into a datepicker:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker form-control" name="text-150" >

var DatePicker = function () {

   if ($(".datepicker").length === 0) {
       return;
   }

   $(".datepicker").pikaday({
      firstDay: 1,
      format: "D MMM YYYY"
   });
 };
```

The above works fine when the text field is hardcoded with `datepicker` class. But If I have text field and dynamically inject the `datepicker` class after the page has loaded via some event, then how can I bind the datepicker plugin to the text field?

Comment: have you tried [jQuery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)?

Comment: call the `DatePicker` function after you injected the dynamic element

Comment: @azad yes that works now

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you trying to achieve?

```
$( function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
    $('body').append('<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="text-150" >');
    var cl = $('input').attr('class');
    $( "." + cl ).datepicker();
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will help you.

```js
var id=1;
$('#addDate').on('click',function(){
  $("#dates").append('Date '+id+' : <input type="text" id="datepicker'+id+'"><br/>');
  $("#datepicker"+id).datepicker();
  id++;
});
$('#removeAll').on('click',function(){
 $("#dates").html('');
  id=1;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="addDate">Add Date</button>
<button type="button" id="removeAll">Remove All</button>
<div id="dates"></div>
```

Happy Coding...